# its throwing error Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Hello guys I'm new to laravel, so I got confuse. Somebody please clear my doubt, here is my view :

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
 <span class="badge bg-important">{{ $user}}               
  </span>  
 @endforeach;
```

Here is my controller :

```
public function notification()
{
    $users = DB::table('users')->where("Active", 0)->count();
    return view('admin.layout.master',compact($users));
}
```

It's throwing error ;

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

and if I remove `foreach` it's working fine can anybody clear my doubt why this occur

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
compact($users)
```

to

```
compact('users')
```

The parameter is the name of the variable not the actual vaiable itself

Comment: i already used it its work when i remove foreach loop don't know why this happen thanks for you reply

Answer (score 0):

First, as @meda stated, you need to fix your `compact()` statement.

The other issue is that your `$users` variable is being set to an integer, not the collection of users. Currently you are just counting the active users, not getting them.

Change

```
$users = DB::table('users')->where("Active", 0)->count();
```

To

```
$users = DB::table('users')->where("Active", 0)->get();
```